# How to plot data in 3D with a top shadow

Tags: python

I am trying to plot my 3d data in such a way it gives both 2d and 3d overview at a same time (e.g. projection of 3d on the top as 2d). May someone help me out here.
**My attempt:**

```
x=np.linspace(30, 40, 100)
y=np.linspace(70, 80, 100)
z=np.linspace(100, 400, 100)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, color = "green")
plt.title("simple 3D scatter plot")

plt.show()
```

**What I get:**

[image]

**What I am looking for:**

In the attached figure, the two 2d view is shown on bottom and left right axis. I want to plot it on top view.

[image]